# Using seperate Bounded Context Person Management (Speakers, Chairs, Authors, Participants) in Conference Management?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

We built an application for planning the scientific program of conferences including rooms, sessions, lectures (oral oder poster presentations), **speakers**, **chairs** and so on (**program planning context**).

One important part are scientific **papers** with their **authors** from the paper submission which also can lead to lectures or poster presentations.

The **paper management context** is a separate bounded context and uses an external api to sync data between a third party tool. It acts as an Anti-Corruption Layer (ACL) for the program planning context.

The concept of speaker, chair and author has a **person** in common. I want to introduce a seperate **person management context** to reduce duplicated people and reuse unique people in program planning and paper management contexts using the unique identifier of the person and display information through composite UI. Later we want to integrate another **conference registration context** with the same ACL logic for another third party api.

As I learned from many books, blogs etc. only the person management context should own the person's data and create new instances.
The consequence would be to create a new person per author (sync api call) when importing all data from the external paper management api or alternatively use one batch call at the beginning.

Is this coupling to high? Should I store duplicated personal data of the authors in the paper management context? This seems wrong and makes the deduplication hard.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question. This question is overly broad.

Comment: thanks and nice to be here, i tried to shorten it a bit

Comment: Its all about how you define the context for the data. When the context of the data is different than it is not duplication even if some values are the same. In the paper management service you would only store Author data relevant to a paper, maybe his name and age. In the author service you would store relevant data to describing an author which also include name and age but context is different. If you need a person service then you describe the person there not an author. Though the person-job theoretically might be a jobid referring to author.

Comment: Author data like "isPresentingAuthor", "isCorrespondingAuthor", "position" and all institutes the author worked for the paper is in the paper context. Name, E-Mail, ... would be only for displaying reasons in the paper context. As I read in many articles/books "duplicate data in other contexts if the context is not able to work without asking another service". By using composite UI you can still do all paper relevant work like "reorder author", "change affiliation", "change presenting author" in the paper context. If the person service fails, we just couldnt display a name. sounds that right?

Comment: the concept of Person is nonsense. In DDD a "person" plays a role in a given context, so it's either a speaker, attendee or writer, nothing else. For what I read you just care about the conceptual identity of those concepts and that's it. Having a Person BC is wrong, in fact having a class "person" (in OO) is wrong from a philosophical conception. You might think all these are users and so replace the Person BC by a User BC, but that's wrong too. Remember you just care about the values of who is who in different BCs.

Comment: Thanks. Then it is an Attendee BC which handles all authors, speakers, Congress organizers, registrant etc.? I want to add new authors, speakers etc. based on all attendees/people already attend on the conference.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider your use of DDD. This might be something more easily solved without the constraints of DDD because it sounds like it has a lot of data.
Assuming you want to keep DDD then you would need to decouple your contexts. There are several ways to decouple your contexts but my 2 favorite are:

1. Domain Events
2. Rest Api

You can trigger a domain event after you extract each author and the event can be handled by any context needing it. You could consume a rest api where you can send author data and it'll serve as the "Application Service" for your second domain.

I think I understood your problem/question. Correct me if I haven't solved it or addressed something completely different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already thought about an AuthorCreated Event and the person context could add a new person to the conference. But then I have the problem that this person could be updated in the person context and at the same time in the paper management context. Both sites could emit an event e.g. PersonUpdated and Author Updated which which would leed to a conflict. Does this help?

Comment: Keep in mind that those 2 entities should be different and based on the context. There shouldn't be a lot of times where they need to be synched. It should be possible for them to change and not affect each other, especially if you have a well defined ubiquitous language and you have properly defined your context. If there absolutely needs to be a synch, your domain will need to be smart enough to resolve any conflicts.

Comment: Exactly and in the ubiquitous language you can say "an author is a person who writes a paper for different institutes and can be of different type (presenting, corresponding, co-author)". That was the reason for me to extract the concept of person. Like in eCommerce examples where the customer is mostly only an id in other contexts like Shipping but extended e.g. "shipping address" which is only relevant for shipping context.